# Is it possible to declare a local variable without overriding the original for the child processes?

Tags: shell-script, zsh

If I have a pre-existing ENV variable, is it possible to declare a new local variable with the child process using the original value?

Keep in mind, I don't know which variables the child process will use. So saving the value of the original and doing `var=original mycmd -with -args` won't be sufficient.

```shell
# print.sh:
echo "from print.sh: $MY_VAR"

# local.sh:
run () {
  declare MY_VAR="should not be seen"
  bash print.sh
}
MY_VAR="original" run
```

The above prints: `from print.sh: should not be seen` instead of: `from print.sh: original` even if I use `local`, `declare`, etc. in the `function body`

I was hoping `declare/local/typeset` had some options, but I haven't found any that says: set a value for this variable locally, but child processes use the original.

Comment: You could make the variable read-only, which would result in an error during run()...

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't answer the question.  I re-wrote the question to be clearer.

Comment: You're explicitly resetting the variable, so my best suggestion is to do the reset and whatever else run() wants to do with that new value all in a subshell -- `run () { ( MY_VAR=x; etc); bash print.sh }`

Comment: I've already considered a sub-shell, but I still need to use the variable outside the sub-shell.   The name of the file, `print.sh`, would also in a variable which might clash with the child-process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common convention is to use all-uppercase for environment variables and all-lowercase for script local variables. This way a local variable never clashes with an environment variable.

I don't think zsh has an option to distinguish between the local value and the exported value of a variable. A workaround is to save and restore the value. That does mean listing the variables you want to save.

```
run () {
  typeset -A _saved_variables
  _saved_variables[foo]=$foo _saved_variables[bar]=$bar
  local foo='not seen' bar='not seen either'
  …
  foo=$_saved_variables[foo] bar=$_saved_variables[bar] bash print.sh
}
```

If you want to preserve the whole environment, you can run `typeset -px` to print it out in a parseable form. Note that this won't work if you have exported read-only variables; to handle that case, you'd need to go through the variable names and select only the ones that aren't read-only.

```
run () {
  _saved_variables=`typeset -px`
  local foo='not seen' bar='not seen either'
  …
  (eval $_saved_variables; exec bash print.sh)
}
```

Another option is to structure your script differently. Determine the command you want to run in a subshell, and print it out (suitably quoted) for the parent to execute.

```
run () {
  # you can clobber variables here
  …
  printf %q "bash print.sh"
}
eval $(run)
```

Comment: You can indeed clash with environment variables by using lowercase variable names. trying running `path=1` and running a command or `manpath=/dev/null` if you have a `MANPATH` variable set. zsh has a quite a few lowercase shell variables that affects the shell's behavior. `zle_bracketed_paste`, `cdpath`, `fpath` to name a few.

Comment: nor is `typeset -px` a viable way of saving the 'entire environment'. `env 123=abc zsh -c 'env;typeset -px'`. typeset's output will lack the 123 variable.

Comment: @llua You can't do anything about the variables that the shell pre-defines, including zsh's lowercase variables (but they won't clobber uppercase variables if you don't modify them, and if they do it's because they're uppercase variables with a standard meaning). If you need to preserve those, use something other than a shell. As for environment variables with invalid names, the shell won't clobber them.

Answer (score 2):

The question is aimed at Zsh. But, for Bash and mksh users, it's possible w/ caveats: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/272576/42107