# Which shells have functions where "local" does not alter exported variables for child processes?

Tags: shell, shell-script, environment-variables, variable, function

In the example below, an `export`ed variable is re-set as  `local` in a function. Bash, Zsh, Fish don't pass on the original value to the child process. Are there any shells that make `local` affect the local function body only, but pass the original `export`ed value to the child process?

```sh
function the_func {
  local MY_VAR="new value"

  echo "=== $MY_VAR"  # === prints "new value"
  my -child -process  # === gets MY_VAR="original"
}

export MY_VAR="original"
the_func
```

A subshell and readonly variables won't be good enough because the  variables are also needed outside of the subshell.  The args or name of the command could be in a variable that might class with the child process.

Answer (score 3):

1. mksh
2. Bash with `declare +x MY_VAR=value`. (`local +x` and `typeset +x` also work).

However, in Bash, it would fail under these conditions:

```
my_func () {
   local +x MY_VAR="..."
   bash my.sh  # ERROR in Bash: this gets "original" instead of "2nd def"
               # Works in mksh: "2nd def" is passed.
}
export MY_VAR="original"
MY_VAR="2nd def" my_func
```

It behaves intuitively in [mksh](https://www.mirbsd.org/mksh.htm).